# Interrupting a thread running a Cypher query causes exceptions

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have some tasks that are run in their own threads, each one executing a method which wraps a Cypher Query that gathers some statistics and updates some nodes. 
 That method is marked as @Transactional (Using Spring)
Each thread executes the same query, with a different node id param for start.
Now, occasionally, some threads 'hang' or take too long to execute and I would like to be able to interrupt them. 
So I wrote a class using  Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() in order to schedule a cancel() after a certain timeout.
What is happening is that I get all sorts of exceptions, transaction related. App logs

> org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.UnderlyingStorageException: Unable to load    position[3822] @[34398] 
>   Caused by: javax.transaction.xa.XAException: Logical log unable to mark 1P-commit [4]  
>   Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException: null
>       at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:184) ~[na:1.6.0_65]

Neo4j version is 1.9.5 embedded, running on Mac
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interrupting Threads is not a good idea. Esp. with nio weird things happen.

I think it is much better to use the built-in mechanism in Neo4j for this.

Stefan Armbruster wrote a blog on how to use the "Guard" mechanism to stop long running cypher queries, see here:

http://blog.armbruster-it.de/2013/09/some-experiments-with-ratpack-and-neo4j/

Check out the "Terminate Queries" part & code.

Answer (score 0):

### Test case and workaround

I created an issue on github, just to see what opinion Matrix team have on this. So far I like Neo4j very much, but this is real issue for me.

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/3977#issuecomment-74735972

I didn't like the guard solution for more reasons, so I wrote little thread class, which solves interrupted problem. It does not solve long running query problem fully because it will keep running in background, but your code will not wait for it to finish. 
  I'm testing it for few days already and it feels usable.